# How to find the Index of string in java array from the given string value

Tags: java

```
creditTIDstatusArray=[93312263-1-09722612223, 99802001-1-09102842369, 99802002-1-09102842369];
creditTIDstatusList.addAll(Arrays.asList(creditTIDstatusArry));
searchValue="99802002-1".

int retval=creditTIDstatusList.indexOf("99802002-1");
System.out.println("The element at index is:" retval);
```

> Output: 2

Please let me know how I can find the index of the given above(searchValue)element.

Comment: try to print content of creditTIDstatusArray or creditTIDstatusList, what do you see?

Comment: @Bursov it prints like this  [93312263-1-09722612223, 99802001-1-09102842369, 99802002-1-09102842369]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you never have posted the reproducible code.
Assumptions

1. `creditTIDstatusArray` is a `String` type array.
2. Your search query always stays in front of each `String` value in the array.
3. Multiple indexes may start with the same search value.

```
String[] creditTIDstatusArray=new String[]{"93312263-1-09722612223", "99802001-1-09102842369", "99802002-1-09102842369"};
String searchValue="99802002-1";
for (int i = 0; i < creditTIDstatusArray.length; i++) {
    if(creditTIDstatusArray[i].startsWith(searchValue)){
        System.out.println("Index :" + I); // this will print all the indexes that starts with searchvalue
    }
}
```

I am not sure why you have added the array into a list and then searched `index of` because it will never work as you are searching only part of a `String` rather than the whole `value` or `object`.